# xml xpath domdocument make id number available

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have the follow Code to save an XML Document into database.
The Question is, how can I make the ID number (first array instance)
available?

best regards

```
 <?php
$xmlObject = new DOMDocument();
$xmlObject->load('xml99.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlObject);

$query = "item/sizes/size/*[name()='sizebarcode' or name()='stock']";

$shifted_values = iterator_to_array($xpath->query($query));

$grouped = array();

$coordinator = function(DOMNode $node) use ( &$grouped, $xpath ) {
$result = $xpath->query('../../../number', $node);
$number = $result->item(0)->nodeValue;

$resultRank = $xpath->Query('../sizeid', $node);
$rank = $resultRank->item(0)->nodeValue;

$grouped[$number][$rank][ $node->nodeName ] = $node->nodeValue;
};

array_map($coordinator, $shifted_values);

var_dump($grouped);  
?>
```

Result shows like that:

```
array(11) {
["011000016"]=>
  array(7) {
[24]=>
array(2) {
  ["sizebarcode"]=>
  string(3) "410"
  ["stock"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  }
  [25]=>
   array(2) {
  ["sizebarcode"]=>
  string(3) "420"
  ["stock"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  }

}
next ID number...
```

My question is, how can I make the ID number available?
like this:

So I can use the XML DATA to Insert into database.

```
 array(11) {
["0"]=> "011000016"
  array(7) {
[24]=>
array(2) {
  ["sizebarcode"]=>
  string(3) "410"
  ["stock"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  }
```

best regards

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid array structure.  This question is currently Unclear.